# jQuery call .GET() twice and get results

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, async-await, get

In my program, I need to make GET call, then pass returned data to another GET call, and then return results. When it is happening, I want my program to wait until data is returned.

Right now I figured out something like this:

```
    async function getPlaceTag(lat, lng) {
        jQuery.get('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lng)
            .done(function (data) {
                jQuery.get('http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];way(' + data.osm_id + ');out;')
                    .done(function (data2) {
                        console.log(data2);
                    });
            });
    }
```

Then I use it:

```
    mymap.on('moveend', async function () {
        let coords = myMarker.getLatLng();
        console.log('call tag');
        await getPlaceTag(coords.lat, coords.lng);  // I want to wait here until it gets done
        console.log('after call');
    })
```

And I get:

```
call tag
after call
[GET data]    <-- printed my data after ~1sec
```

I want it to get that data and print it before "after call" is printed:

```
call tag
[GET data]
after call
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return` or `await` the result of calling `done` in order to make your `async` function wait for it to complete.

Using `.then` (instead of `.done`) and a non-`async` function:

```
function getPlaceTag(lat, lng) {
    return jQuery.get('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lng)
        .then(function (data) {
            return jQuery.get('http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];way(' + data.osm_id + ');out;')
                .then(function (data2) {
                    return data2;
                });
        });
}
```

Using an `async` function with `await` and `return`:

```
async function getPlaceTag(lat, lng) {
    const data1 = await jQuery.get('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lng);
    return jQuery.get('http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];way(' + data1.osm_id + ');out;');
}
```

Note that in both cases, it works because jQuery was updated to make its `Deferred` a valid promise.

---

FWIW, I wouldn't use jQuery for this, I'd use the standard `fetch` isntead. I'd have a utility function:

```
async function fetchText(url, init) {
    const response = await fetch(url, init);
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    return response.text();
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
async function getPlaceTag(lat, lng) {
    const data1 = await fetchText('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lng);
    return fetchText('http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];way(' + data1.osm_id + ');out;')
}
```

Simiarly I have `fetchJSON` for when I need to read and parse the result as JSON, etc.

I don't just use `fetch` directly because of [the footgun in the `fetch` API](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html)¹: it *fulfills* its promise even when there's an HTTP error (like 404 or 500), rather than rejecting it.

---

¹ That's a post on my anemic little blog.

Comment: Works fine, Thanks for all the solutions!